# How to render data as grid/table in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, npm

i am receiving data from external micro service which is not standard all the time it will be like dynamic data. it may contain table data or not. also it can have some metadata information above the grid. how can i render or identify the table data and render as grid also add meta information above the grid.

below is my sample data

```
{ 

   'Line1':
    [ 
      { word: 'Welcome to Angular', x: 10, y: 18 }
    ],

   'Line2':
    [ 
      { word: 'Name', x: 10, y: 24 },
      { word: 'ID', x: 105, y: 22 } 
    ],
   'Line3':
    [
      { word: 'Michael', x: 9, y: 50 },
      { word: '213', x: 103, y: 49 } 
    ],
    'Line4':
    [ 
      { word: 'Andrew', x: 11, y: 77 },
      { word: '123[enter image description here][1]', x: 105, y: 74 } 
     ],
    'Line5':
     [ 
       { word: 'John', x: 10, y: 103 },
       { word: '323', x: 105, y: 103 } 
     ]
}
```

and the output should be like below,

```
  Welcome to Angular

  Name      ID
  Michael   213
  Andrew    123
  John      323
```

How can i achieve the above format. i am using angular 4 for UI. is there any grid that support my requirement?

Note: i am getting coordinates of the word inside my response from server.

Comment: Google Array.prototype.map, Object.keys ...

Comment: how would i differentiate between metadata and table like data

Comment: In that example, any property that has an array with two items, the word key of those is table data.

Comment: What if i have another value in first array which not a part of grid

Comment: If you cannot change the server side so that it'd send something that makes sense, you'll just have to try and make sense of the data client side. Find the rules and react to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
const tabularData = Object.keys(sampleData)
    .filter(key => sampleData[key].length > 1)
    .sort()
    .map(key => sampleData[key].map(item => item.word.replace(/\[.*\]/g, '')));
// -->
[
    ['Name', 'Id'],
    ['Michael', '213'],
    ...
]

const otherData = Object.keys(sampleData)
    .filter(key => sampleData[key].length === 1)
    .sort()
    .map(key => sampleData[key][0].word);
// -->
['Welcome to Angular']
```